# Blank/Empty WSDL file

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf

I'm struggling to have my WCF web service output a wsdl file with no luck so far (it's empty?).

the svc file:

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Service="xxx.WCF.SubsetMID" CodeBehind="SubsetMID.svc.cs"
Factory="System.ServiceModel.Activation.WebServiceHostFactory"
%>
```

the cs file :

```
namespace xxx.WCF
{
    [ServiceContract(Namespace = "SubsetMID")]
    public interface ISubsetMID
    {
        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(BodyStyle=WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped)]
        long[] GetMIDs(Guid guid, int subsetID);
    }

    [DataContract]
    [AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Required)]
    public class SubsetMID : ISubsetMID
    {
        public long[] GetMIDs(Guid guid, int subsetID)
        {
            [...]

            return returnValue;
        }
    }
}
```

My web config file :

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <services>
    <service name="xxx.WCF.SubsetMID">
      <endpoint address=""
                binding="wsHttpBinding"
                contract="xxx.WCF.ISubsetMID" />

      <endpoint address="mex"
                binding="mexHttpBinding"
                contract="IMetadataExchange" />
    </service>
  </services>
  <behaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
      <behavior>
        <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
      </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
  <serviceHostingEnvironment
      multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"
      aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"
  />
</system.serviceModel>
```

I don't get any error when I access the wsd (`http://.../SubsetMID.svc?wsdl`) but it's just a blank page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following is a best guess based on some research I did - I'm not that familiar with RESTful WCF services, so I might be wrong but this should give you a starting point at least.

You didn't specify, but it looks like you're trying to write a RESTful WCF service.  I'm not entirely certain, because you use `wsHttpBinding` in your endpoint, but you also decorate the method in the service with `[WebInvoke]`.

In any event, REST services do not have WSDLs - that's a SOAP thing.  Additionally, I believe WCF supports REST with the `webHttpBinding`.  As you are using `WebServiceHostFactory` in your .svc file, I **think** this is what is happening:

You do not have any `webHttpBinding` endpoints defined.  WCF will create a default `webHttpBinding` endpoint, with the address based on the location of the .svc file.  However, when default endpoints are used according to [WebServiceHost Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.web.webservicehost.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1):

`...the WebServiceHost also disables the HTTP Help page and the Web Services Description Language (WSDL) GET functionality so the metadata endpoint does not interfere with the default HTTP endpoint.`

If you're writing a REST service, you won't need a WSDL.  If you're planning on having a SOAP service, then use `ServiceHostFactory` in your .svc file and remove the `[WebInvoke]` attribute from the method.

Again, this is a (relatively) educated guess, and it may be wrong, but it's a place to start.

Comment: I don't really nned my service to be REST. All I want is a way to publish it and have a easy way to reference it in a new project. Halas, all I can read on Internet is about self hosted WCF service, Google even translate "svc" into "wcf" which makes searchs really hard. :(

Comment: Then changing your .svc file markup to use `ServiceHostFactory` and removing the `[WebInvoke]` attribute on the service method(s) should do the trick for you. Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

Im guessing that you are using a wcf service website project  which contains the svc file. if you dont, i strongly recommend you to do that and set it as the startup project in your solution, so you could debug it properly. for me, and good chances that for you too if you followed codeproject step by step instructions, the problem was that i didn't reference the wcf services from the website, thus the directive in the svc couldn't find the service. hope i helped