# Unable to resolve WCF "Metadata publishing for this service is currently disabled" error

Tags: vb.net, wcf, web-services, .net-4.0

I'm branching out into .Net web services and unfortunately am a newbie at it.  I've decided to build WCF service instead of asp.net service because of online recommendations. My ultimate goal is to learn iOS and other mobile programming.  I'm familiar with vb.net and c# standard and web applications.

I'm receiving a "Metadata publishing for this service is currently disabled" error when trying to test from a URL.  I've research and tried implementing "fixes" for this issue, but still come up short.  Can someone please look at my code and see what I'm doing wrong?

**Webconfig file**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" strict="false" 
                 explicit="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>
  </system.web>
  <connectionStrings>
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.serviceModel>
<services>
<services>
<service name="CCT_Main_SRV.Service1" behaviorConfiguration="BehConfig">
<endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="CCT_Main_SRV.Service1" behaviorConfiguration="web">
</endpoint>
<endpoint contract="IMetadataExchange" binding="mexHttpBinding" address="mex" />
</service>
</services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="BehConfig">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="web">
          <webHttp/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true">
    </serviceHostingEnvironment>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

**.VB File**

```
Imports System.ServiceModel
Imports System

Namespace CCT_Main_SRV.Service1

<ServiceContract()>
Public Interface CCT_Main_SRV

    <OperationContract()>
    <WebGet(UriTemplate:="Get_Device_Authenication", _
            RequestFormat:=WebMessageFormat.Json, _
            ResponseFormat:=WebMessageFormat.Json, _
            BodyStyle:=WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped)>
    Function Authenicate_Device_Manager(ByVal Device_Name As String, _
                                        ByVal Auth_Key As String) _
             As List(Of Device_Authenication)

    <WebGet()>
    <OperationContract()>
    Function Authenicate_Device_Manager_Non_JSON(ByVal Device_Name As String, _
                                                 ByVal Auth_Key As String) _
             As List(Of Device_Authenication)
End Interface

<DataContract()>
Public Class Device_Authenication

    <DataMember()>
    Public Property Device_Name As String
    <DataMember()>
    Public Property Active As Boolean
    <DataMember()>
    Public Property Return_String As String
End Class
```

**svc.vb file**

```
Imports System.ServiceModel
Imports System.Web.Script.Serialization
Imports System.ServiceModel.Activation
Imports System.ServiceModel.Web
Imports System.ServiceModel.Description


Namespace CCT_Main_SRV.Service1
    Public Class Service1
        Implements CCT_Main_SRV


    Dim host As WebServiceHost = New WebServiceHost(GetType(Service1), New Uri("http://pmh-vmutility-1/cct_web_srv_test/:8000/"))
    Dim ep As ServiceEndpoint = host.AddServiceEndpoint(GetType(CCT_Main_SRV), New WebHttpBinding(), "")


        Public Function Authenicate_Device_Manager(ByVal Device_Name As String, _
                                               ByVal Auth_Key As String) _
           As List(Of Device_Authenication) _
           Implements CCT_Main_SRV.Authenicate_Device_Manager

        End Function
    End  Class
End Namespace
```

Comment: It looks to me like you're trying to mix and match SOAP and REST.  WebHttpBinding is for RESTful WCF.  What are you doing when you get the error? Trying to add a Service Reference or using SVCUTIL?  See this http://stackoverflow.com/a/17466832/745969 for a situation similar to yours.

Comment: @Tim.  I'm not familiar with SOAP and REST.  Basically i'm trying to build a WCF so it can be my connection between the SQL DB and iOS apps.  I will research both of those procedures.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
service name="CCT_Main_SRV.Service1"
```

Should be:

```
service name="Service1"
```

Or if it resides in a Web Application:

```
service name="ProjectName.Web.Service1"
```

It should match the fully qualified name of your service

`{namespace}.{class}` yours does not have a namespace.

Comment: Thanks for you help.  I've added a namespace to my code and am no longer seeing the "Metadata publishing" error.  I've also added a Webhost to actually test the service using internet explorer. I'm now receiving another error message "The type 'Crash_Cart_Web_SRV_Test.Service1', provided as the Service attribute value in the ServiceHost directive, or provided in the configuration element system.serviceModel/serviceHostingEnvironment/serviceActivations could not be found"  Thanks Again

Comment: Lets close this question out and open a new one, that way the community has a new searchable question/answer since this is a different error.